# reading txt file using php , storing content to database

Tags: php, database, csv, explode

I am having **one txt file**, with data simillar to below. I need to read the file and store the content in database using php, I am trying to explode the line and read it into array, but 7th column itself contains "," so not able to explode it properly using ",". Any help on this, how it can be done.

```
"MN", 2215," 309   ","4002 ",10,"10463","VAN TULL, GORDON     ",000003120,"  ",1, 2, 4, "Y" 
"MN", 2215," 309   ","4002 ",10,"10463","RODRIGUEZ, RANDY     ",000003120,"  ",1, 2, 4, "Y"
```

I am trying following

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "r")


1) $line = fgetcsv($handle,",")
    this is not working as column 7th itself have "," in its value.

2)
   $Line = fgets($handle);
   $data=explode(",",$Line);
   if count($data)>13 
    // concatenating col 6 and 7
```

Comment: *I am trying* I don't see your attempts! Please show them to us

Comment: there are specific functions in php for dealing with csv files, use them

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention how you're trying to parse the csv, but I'm guessing you're just splitting it around the comma.  Instead, try [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways at least

1. SIMPLE way is to replace all *necessary* commas with some special character and explode
2. bit programmatic - use regex

   ```
   $contents = file_get_contents(__dir__.'/sample.txt');

   $rows = explode(PHP_EOL, $contents);

   foreach($rows as $row){
       $cols = preg_split('/,(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)/', $row);
       // do what you want to do with cols, which is an array of columns
   }
   ```